# I/O completion port silently fails to read completely

Tags: windows, file-io, io-completion-ports

I'm developing a program that needs to write a large amout of data to disk then read back much smaller amount of data back later on.  It needs to "bin" related data together then once it figures out what to do with it, then it can process the data further.  It's basically acting like a database, but with temp files on disk.  Portions of the temp files get reused fairly frequently as I don't care about the data on disk after I read it back out, so that portion of the file can be recycled.  I'm using I/O completion ports to implement this because sequential I/O is simply too slow.

The problem is that sometimes when I read the data, I don't get all of it back.  For example, I will zero out my read buffer, do a read operation of, say, 20 bytes, and when the corresponding completion event triggers, some or even none of my read buffer will match what should be on disk, but all of it won't be zeroed out.  Occasionally, I can detect this and try sleeping 5 seconds and reading the same portion again, and it matches what I read in the first try.  This is taking place on a top of the line SSD, so 5 seconds should be plenty to flush to disk.  However, when I stop my application and look at the contents of the file, it's correct on disk.  It's as if the previous write hasn't flushed to disk and it tried reading old data.

To test that theory, I tried writing 0xFF on entire sections as I read them.  When this error happened again, my read buffer did not contain 0xFFs as I would have expected.  So presumably, I'm not reading old data.

I also checked to make sure that the number of bytes returned from the completion event matched the number of bytes that I passed to ReadFile, and they do match.  There is no error returned by the completion event or by ReadFile (other than ERROR_IO_PENDING).  I am creating my temp files with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, and FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS.

I also tried waiting for all pending writes for a given portion of the file to complete before trying to read, but to no avail.  I would hope that Windows would do that for me, but it isn't covered in any documentation that I've read.

I'm really at a loss as to why I'm getting what look to be partial or corrupted reads.  I'm really just looking for some ideas that might cause this behavior because I'm all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sound of things you're firing off writes and reads to the same portions of the same file and sometimes the data that the read returns isn't what you think you have previously written.

I assume you are waiting for the write completion for a piece of data before issuing a read request for the same area of the file? If not the read could be occurring before the write completes? When lots of data is being written to the same disk the write completions may begin to slow down and writes may spend more time pending (watch out for the resources that this consumes!)

Personally I'd include my own memory cache layer which knows about the data block until the write completion occurs - you can then satisfy reads for this part of the file from your cache if the write has not yet completed.

Comment: I think that I was trusting Windows too much.  Based on my previous testing, I thought that windows would not let you read from a portion of the disk that had pending writes.  I tested this by slamming my hard drive with a few hundred megs worth of small, nonsequential writes, then tried to read the last few sections that I had written to.  The reads would never complete until all or nearly all of the writes had completed (10+ seconds after the reads were initially queued).I now think this is an incorrect assumption.

Comment: Also, I thought that it would be enough to count the number of bytes completed by writes to determine if I could read from a given file portion.  This doesn't seem to be accurate either because writes can complete out of order.  Now I'm waiting on the specific write to complete before attempting to read, and so far, that seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: Neither of these two observations surprise me. Glad you fixed your assumptions.